# list of lists.. of lists? Applying regex and nltk

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, nltk

OK, I simplify my question:

I have a list(of documents) that contains some lists(of sentences) as `str`. Like `a = [['Sent1 from first doc!','Sent2 from first doc.'],['Sent1 from 2nd doc.','Sent2 from 2nd doc.']]`

Now I try to split each sentence into a list of words.. so I'll probably have a first list(of documents) that contains a list(of sentences), where each contains a list(of words from that sentence as str).

Unfortunately, my code produces a list(of sentences) which contains each word.. therefore, I lose track from which document each sentence came from.

My code looks like this:

```
sentcs = []
for i in range(len(a)): 
    for p in range(len(a[i])):        
        spr = re.findall(r'[A-Z]?[^A-Z\s]+|[A-Z]+', a[i][p])
        sentcs.append(spr)
```

But thats not what I want.. I'd like to have a list of list of lists.. or is that bad habit to program something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    li = [('Help! Be nice.'),('Thx. Help appreciated.')]

    for el in li:
        l = el.split(' ',1)
        print(tuple((l[0], l[1:])))  

    ('Help!', ['Be nice.'])
    ('Thx.', ['Help appreciated.'])


from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize   

st = ['Help! Be nice.','Thx. Help appreciated.']

for el in st:
    t = sent_tokenize(el)
    print(tuple((t[0], t[1:])))

('Help!', ['Be nice.'])
('Thx.', ['Help appreciated.'])
```

Comment: Sry, I made a mistake: I do start with a list, but a list of strings 'string=['Help! Be nice.',  'Thx. Help appreciated.']' Therefore, in the second step I have a list that looks like 'string = [['Help!','Be nice'],[Thx.','Help appreciated']]'   I need to split this further into another list, but my code as above just creates a list which contains all sentences splitted into words, so I lose the information to which document it belongs